# Giving a simple function so that sum S(n) is O(f(n))?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Been stuck on this for a while guys.

Consider the sum S(n) = ∑ Log(i). Give a simple function f(n) so that the sum S(n) is O(f(n)). Explain why.

**(The sigma starts at i = 1 and finishes at n)**

How do I do this? Please explain step by step.

Comment: Do you want us to hand it in for you as well?

Comment: I got it wrong, and want to find out how to actually do it.

Comment: @Vimzy, show your implementation so we have something to start with.

Comment: Does simple include constant, transcendental and single-parameter Ackermann (SPA(n) = Ack(n, n))?

Comment: @Kindread I started by trying to prove S(n) is <= to n^2 through induction. I basically got a 0 for it, so I'm pretty lost and not quite sure where to begin.

Comment: S(n)=O(n²) is a perfectly valid answer, unless you were asked to provide a tight bound.

Comment: IMO O(n²) should get at least half the attainable merit if the bound was not requested to be tight.

Answer (score 1):

Just because `log` is monotonic:

`sum[i=1..n]log(i) <= sum[i=1..n]log(n) = n*log(n)`

So it's `O(n*log(n))`

And to confirm that we cannot improve this bound:

`sum[i=1..n]log(i) >= sum[i=n/2..n]log(i) >= sum[i=n/2..n]log(n/2) = (n/2)*log(n/2)`

So it's `Omega(n*log(n))`

Answer (score 0):

Any function g(n) that bounds Log(n) above can be used. Indeed, Log(n)=O(g(n)) implies S(n)=O(f(n)) where f(n)=∑ g(i).

For instance g(n)=n establishes S(n)=O(n²), using the triangular numbers formula.

If you want a tight bound, you can notice that ∑Log(i)=Log(n!), and use the [Stirling formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

If you are not allowed to use Stirling's formula, take the sum of the ceilings of Lg(i) (base 2  logarithm). They follow a regular pattern, starting from 1:
0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5...

The length of the runs double every time, so that the sum to n has no more than Lg(n) distinct runs and the sum is bounded by n.ceiling(Lg(n)+1).

The reasoning is valid for natural logarithms as all logarithms are proportional: Log(i) = Lg(i) / Lg(2).

∑Log(i) = O(n.Log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out from this [link](http://mohalgorithmsorbit.blogspot.nl/2014/06/triple-nested-loops-two-linear-loops.html).

[image]

@Yves Daoust nailed the summation values. In a nutshell (when n = 16, and base = 2):

0 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 1 + (2 * 2) + (4 * 3) + (8 * 4).

Test it with base >= 3 to see the pattern more clearly (To understand the closed form above).